# A good team of version control, project management and hosting for an open-source Java project

Tags: java, version-control, open-source, project-management

I want to release a Java project as open-source, but i am unsure about the right platform and version control system.

**There are three considerations to be thought of:**

1. Which version control software?
2. Which project mangement library?
3. Hosted or on my own server?

### Version Control

Currently i am using **SVN**, and i planned to migrate to **GIT**. But there are also other possibilities like **Mercurial** or **Bazaar**. GIT and Mercurial seem to be very similar and i didn't understand the pro's and con's of both yet. Also, i'd like to know if there are also any other good alternatives.

### Project Management

Currently, i use **Maven** to manage the Java library dependencies and to carry out the releases. There are also other tools like **Hudson** or **Apache Ivy** and many others. They should be able to handle library dependencies and be able to include currently released versions. Deployment automation is also a plus.

### To host or not to host?

Currently i use an own server to host my SVN code and Maven releases. There are so many hosted solutions out there, and i think one of them would be nice to make it easier for people to join my project if they are interested.

Some of the platforms i heard about or used are for example **Github**, **Bitbucket**, **Google Code** or **Sourceforge**. They should be able to easily integrate support for the selected version control and project management software. Additional stuff for developers like a bugtracker and a wiki are good too and need to be considered useful.

### The best team

So, which combination would you recommend? I'd like to gather all information and create an overview so that people can decide for themselves which setup meets their needs at best.

Comment: git on github. Use Maven because thats what you have now. Then you can iterate with the community.

Comment: Just wanted to tell that i have chosen Git on Github + Maven: https://github.com/alp82/abmash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what we're using, and are pretty happy with:

- Builds with Maven
- Tests with Junit. Integration tests using Maven's failsafe plugin (which uses junit)
- Continuous integration with Jenkins
- Hosted at github as a public repository
- Git as version control system

The only gripe is that Github will limit what you can do with git. You'll have to get used to the pull request mechanism.

**On The Pull request limitations:**

In git, you usually want to have a workflow where people commit to some sort of development branch, and then, after someone approves the changes, it gets merged into a stable branch. Any number of combinations and workflows are possible, and each likes his own.

The trouble is that, if you want to limit what branches people can commit to, you'd have to edit the update hook on github's git repository. This is not possible in github (only post commit hooks are allowed). Github only allows all or nothing commit rights on the whole repository through the collaborator's list, but does not allow branch specific permissions.

To work around that, collaborators would have to clone the repository with the stable branch into a development *repo*, and whenever they have something that's ready to go into stable, they'd have to send a pull request. Following that, whoever controls the repository with the stable branch would pull from the "development repo". In other words, you need to put some of the git branch functionality into branches. This means teams of developers can't share a branch in a repo.

This limitation, however, is not too bad for a project with many individual contributors. It just gets a bit trickier when you have multiple contributing *teams* since they need to have a repository each.

But hey, also consider the visibility that having your project in github will provide, since that's a big plus to attract developers!

Comment: Can you explain that pull request mechanism and why it's a limit?

Comment: I'm not seeing your point about the pull mechanism. You can have users who are authorized to push directly to the main repo, they don't have to contribute via pull requests (it can be helpful with more satellite contributors, though). @Alp: I think (subject to Miquel coming back to explain) you can ignore his comment about pulling.

Comment: Hope my explanation above clarifies this. It was a problem for a large project we developed, where the hierarchy was more complex than individual users. We could let everyone push to the main repo and hope they don't overwrite stable, but eventually someone messes up...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that's interesting information.

Answer (score 4):

[Google Code](http://code.google.com) is currently free and offers source control ([your choice of subversion, mercurial, or git](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6#Working_with_your_Source_Repository)) with command-line integration, issue tracking, and wiki. I wouldn't bet it would be free for closed projects forever, but I suspect it always will be for open-source.

[GitHub](https://github.com/plans) is free for open-source projects, and offers really powerful web tools as well as command-line `git` integration. Also with issue-tracking, wikis, pull-requests, etc.

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) is a similar site, also for open-source projects, that does much the same thing with Mercurial. Also with issue-tracking, wikis, pull-requests, etc.

---

This is a Community Wiki answer because questions asking for the "best" are best served by a wiki-style response. Feel free to edit this answer to add your view.

Comment: what about the choice of version control?

Comment: @Alp: `git` and `mercurial` are very nearly feature-equivalent (I don't know `subversion` enough to say anything about it), I don't think you're going to go wrong with either of them. (Linus Torvalds is on record as saying if he'd been aware of what `mercurial` were doing when he got sick of the old system they were using for the kernel and wrote `git`, he probably wouldn't have bothered.)

Comment: @Alp: You may find this helpful: http://kylecordes.com/2007/linux-git-distributed

Answer (score 1):

If you want **real freedom** of choice in tools and workflows you **have** to see at [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/) (hosted or running own instance)

1. Most of First-Class SCM (hg, git, svn)
2. Project management
3. Colaboration tools for full ALM
4. Free and closed projects
5. Biggest space for your data in free SCM-hostings

Comment: Looks promising. Does it also offer Maven support?

Comment: I know nothing about it, but, BTW, Maven is **local builder**, yes? You can try to start Maven locally using special Web-hooks

Comment: There are also public Maven repositories, which is also very important for me.